# Using Plates in PHP

Tags: php, plates

I'm new to using Plates template library for PHP. I have a few questions about how to use it.

I'm looking through the docs I don't see a way to set a global layout. Is there not a way to do that?

I'm using it inside of Codeigniter. Ideally, I'd like to set the layout in the MY_Controller file for most of the site and change when needed in a controller extending MY_Controller; for instance, setting the main site layout and then for the admin panel setting the admin layout in the Auth_Controller that all of the other admin controllers extend.

Changing the layout of a particular set of templates I'd have to go through and edit all of those files. This doesn't seem ideal. Or even just passing a sidebar data for a particular layout has to be done by passing the sidebar data to each template and from each template to the layout in every file. This seems very redundant. Am I missing something?

To clarify Plates is the template system/library, http://platesphp.com/

Example of what I'm talking about.
The admin layout has a sidebar of all the admin URLs. This comes from a config file that's loaded and it has it's own template/view file.

I call the template and pass the data from the controller

```
// I created a library file that extends the Plates library so it can be easily loaded from the CI loader class
$data['sidebar_data'] = array(
    'navigation'=>'Navigation',
    'assets'=>'Assets',
    'config'=>'Config'
);
$data['controller_name'] => 'Users';
$this->plates->render('admin/whatever_page', $data);
```

Inside of the template file/current page

```
<?php $this->layout('layouts/admin', ['title' => $controller_name, 'sidebar_data' => $sidebar_data])
// stuff for this page
?>
```

Inside of the sidebar navigation template that gets loaded in the admin layout file

```
<ul class="menu vertical">
    <?php foreach($sidebar_data as $url => $label):?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= '/admin/' . $url ?>"><?= $label ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Then the layout

```
// there's a HEAD method in here that has the $title variable
<header class="row expanded collapse">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="top-bar">
                <div class="top-bar-left">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><strong>Site Name</strong></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="top-bar-right">
                    <ul class="menu dropdown align-right" data-dropdown-menu>
                        <li>
                            <?= $current_user ?></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"> | </li>
                        <li>
                            <?= $this->insert('auth/logout_form') ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
        <div class="left-panel">
            <?= $this->insert('adminnav', ['sidebar_data' => $sidebar_data])?>
        </div>
        <div class="main-panel">
            <?= $this->section('content')?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div id="adminmodal" class="reveal" data-reveal>
        <button class="close-button" type="button" data-close aria-label="Close modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).foundation()</script>
    <?= $this->insert('_blocks/googleanalytics')?>
```

Having to pass the same data from every controller method to the controller's view/template then from that to the layout/other templates is very redundant.

Comment: http://platesphp.com/templates/inheritance/

Comment: Yes. I've looked at that, but that doesn't really solve the redundancy issue I have of having to pass the same data to the template and then to the  layout in/for every template.

Comment: I edited my post to add an example of what I'm talking about. Where $sidebar_data and $controller_name has to be a set in every controller method's $data being passed to the template being rendered then passed around from there. Is there's a better way to do the examples above?
I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but ideally I'd like to say something like $this->plates->set_var('title', 'Users') and that would be accessible in all of the files loaded by the Plates library, from the templates to the final layout called without having to pass around all of the data through the different files.

Comment: The layout function can take a variable name. You can have global variables in plates as well as local ones. If you make that variable name available via a function or a test  i.e. `$this->layout($this->fullName($pageLayoutName);`. then you can decide which layout to use? It is easy to add functions to plates that have access to anything in PHP. I have just spent some time making plates usable from views. I like plates.

Comment: I like Plates as well. That's why I'm trying to learn how to use it (better). :)
Before I was using Phil Sturgeon's basic CI template library, but it has a number of restrictions that were a hindrance. Plates is way more flexible.

I'll look into this function thing. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array to json

for example:
$this->plates->render('admin/whatever_page', ["data" => json_encode($data)]);

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, how it is solving the problem mentioned in the question